# FATAL ERROR when installing openstack, ubuntu 14.04 with MAAS

Tags: juju, openstack

Documentation followed: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack   where Canonical says "This is by far the best way to install an openstack cloud".

I have installed an Ubuntu 14.04 server with MAAS, have done the MAAS configuration and PXE booted 7 nodes. 
After this, I ran "sudo apt install openstack" that went OK. 
So, "sudo openstack-install"

InstalerGUI: Chosen "Landscape Openstack Autopilot" , next I filled in MAAS credentials.  So, when the installation begins, I get "FATAL ERROR HAS OCCURED: Problem with juju bootstrap"

From ~/.cloud-install/commands.log:

```
DEBUG â¢ 06-17 08:12:43] â¢ cloudinstall.landscape_install â¢ (landscape_install.py, _save_lds_creds, 81)]
   Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG â¢ 06-17 08:12:53] â¢ cloudinstall.multi_install â¢ (multi_install.py, do_install, 137)]
   Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/ubuntu/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap
[DEBUG â¢ 06-17 08:12:53] â¢ cloudinstall.multi_install â¢ (multi_install.py, do_install, 143)]
   Problem during bootstrap: '{'output': 'sudo: juju: command not found\n', 'status': 1}'
[DEBUG â¢ 06-17 08:12:53] â¢ cloudinstall.utils â¢ (utils.py, global_exchandler, 63)]
   Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 78, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 144, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
```

QUESTION: Is there something more missing in the documentation ?  Are there missing some juju packages or installation ?

There are several failures / missing information in the "best way" documentation from canonical, so I am not suprised if that also is the reason why I am stucked with my installation.

Please help

These commands are done during installation:

```
16.june
ubuntu 14.04 LTS with MAAS installed.  IP: 10.250.50.5  

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common  
OK  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable  
OK  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas-maintainers/stable  
OK  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable  
OK  
sudo apt update  
DONE  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  
DONE  
sudo maas-region-admin createadmin      (admin/admin)  
OK - logged into  MAAS  
MAASGUI: imported image 14.04  


sudo -i  
mkdir -p /home/maas  
chown maas:maas /home/maas  
chsh -s /bin/bash maas  
sudo -u maas ssh-keygen  
Copied the public key from /var/lib/maas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to MAAS GUI - "admin" - "preferences" - Add-SSH-key

\# install amtterm (including amttool)
\#
sudo apt-get install amtterm  
AMT_PASSWORD=Password1+  
arp -an |grep -v incom  #to find AMT interfaces.   

\# Configured network parameters in MAAS GUI.

\# MAAS GUI: PXE booted 7 nodes, they are in "ready" mode, and power management is configured. (AMT)

sudo apt install openstack  
done  
sudo openstack-install  
--installerGUI: Chosen Landscape Openstack Autopilot  
--installerGUI: Filled in MAAS credentials  
return: 

******************** Info *************************
* A fatal error has occured: Problem with juju    *
* bootstrap.                                      *
* See ~/.cloud-install/commands for further info. *
* Close                                           *
***************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `sudo apt-get install juju` before run `sudo openstack-install`.